# Android Plot Barchart with Multiple Series

Tags: android, plot, bar-chart

I have been working with Android plot for some weeks now. However, there is one thing I have never been able to fathom and I wonder if some kind soul can help.

I have currently two series of bar chart data being displayed. The thing is that Android Plot overlays them on each other, that is series one on top of series two. The trouble is that when series two is less than series one you never see it as it is hidden behind the series one bar.

My first course of action was to set the opacity of the bars to 50%. This works, however, the result is means the bar charts show four different colours, due to the way one bar's colour can be overlayed on the other.

so

1) Is there a way to change the Z-Ordering of the bars on a per bar basis to ensure the lowest value is drawn on top?

or

2) Is there a way to offset each series to the two series can be displayed side by side?

Thanks for reading. I have my fingers crossed on this one, as I see from stack overflow that many questions relating to Android plot don't get answered often or well. PS: the Author's site is currently down.

Comment: I am a newbie with Android plot and trying to get a basic bar graph going, do you have any basic sample code that may be of help please?